# Is there a way to "ping" an SQL Server via System.Data.SqlClient to see if it's online and ready for queries?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Is there a way to "ping" an SQL Server instance via `System.Data.SqlClient` to see if it's online and ready to accept queries?

The simple code below can be used to find the available SQL Servers on the LAN. But if the list of data sources is saved for later use, how can each instance be "pinged" to see if it's still available?

I could of course send a simple query to each instance, such as `Use _master Select @@Version`, but with a long list that might take a while. If there was some simple function such as `SomeInstance.IsAvailable`, that would be much better.

```
Dim sqlEnumInst As SqlDataSourceEnumerator = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance
Dim sqlEnumData As System.Data.DataTable = sqlEnumInst.GetDataSources()
For Each row As DataRow In sqlEnumData.Rows
    Dim srvn As String = row("ServerName").ToString
    Dim insn As String = row("InstanceName").ToString
    Dim svrStr As String = srvn & "\" & insn
    Console.WriteLine(svrStr)
Next
```

Comment: You'd have to try to open a `SqlConnection`.

Comment: "with a long list that might take a while". Don't test them in series. Do them in parallel

Comment: Ahh thank you both. I'll run a bunch of `OpenAsync()`, perhaps in groups of 10 or some such thing.

Comment: If you like to execute a test query, you can use `SELECT 1;`.

Comment: I like the question. Does anybody know whether it is possible to ping the SQL instance without having access to it? Something in the style of "If you attempt to open the connection and it is either successful or an AccessDeniedException (I made that up) is thrown then the SQL instance is responsive?"

Comment: @Christoph thank you. You could use my piece of code in the OP, but replace `WriteLine()` with `If...Then` to test if the one you're searching for is there, and if found do something and then `Exit For`. But be aware `GetDataSources()` isn't quick. On my network it takes 15-20 seconds to run.